# Creating a User-Adjustable chart in Wordpress

Tags: loop, javascript, forms

I am new to WordPress and I need to create a 'calculator/chart'. I have an excel file with a chart whose values are pulled from different tables with separate formulas, each table having its own set of inputs. Is there a plugin or something I can use to convert this to a live WordPress page where the user can ticker with different inputs and the graph is adjusted based on the formula?

A plugin, a workaround, anything. I need this. Thanks.

Comment: I've built something like this but it's a huge javascript process that modifies input fields based on changes... ...not really something that can just be answered with a little bit of information.  Basically you're accepting user values in the inputs, then running formulas in real time based on those user inputs. I'd suggest you work on creating the 'form' for the chart/calculator and then include the inputs and the formulas and try to tackle it all section by section - this isn't really a WordPress specific question because the solution would be WP agnostic anyway.

Comment: 'huge javascript process' sounds like kill.

Comment: The formulas themselves are almost 600 lines of code.  The calculator I built was a 'performance tracker' for repair shops using industry standard metrics.  It was based on a spreadsheet, distributed by a manufacturer, that has 140 cells of data over 5 excel tabs.  You complete about 30/40 inputs on the first tab and that then provides you with your shop's performance metrics vs. expected/anticipated metrics... ...it was... ...complicated.  (But it actually works better than excel because I was able to build circular references.)